# How to make a line graph with conditional colors corresponding to columns ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
X   Y   A   B
1   14  1   1
2   34  1   0
3   23  1   1
4   56  0   1
5   78  0   0
6   112 1   1
7   76  0   1
8   98  0   0
```

I'm trying to plot (x and y) but with colors conditional on the values in the columns of A and B. If A is 1, then I want the graph to be colored red and if B is 1 then I want the graph to be colored blue. Also if both A and B are 1, then I want the graph to exhibit both red and blue colors at that point.

Is there a way to do this (in ggplot2 or base R)?

Thanks!

Comment: what are the x and y values

Comment: I just labeled them in the table for reference.

Comment: You can a single point be both red and blue?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to have a single point being both red and blue as you have asked for... if you wanted the A to be red, B to be blue, and A&B to be purple, you could do:

```
# Assuming your dataframe is in `x`:
library(ggplot2)
# the `c(colours)[match(...)]` is a fancy way to select the colour
#   based on the combination of A and B
cols <- c('purple', 'red', 'blue', 'black')[match(paste0(x$A, x$B), c('11', '10', '01', '00'))]
ggplot(x, aes(x=X, y=Y,col=paste(A,B))) + geom_point(col=cols)
```

[image]

Or maybe the A&B could be say red with a blue border -> then we plot the B dots first, slightly bigger, and then plot the A dots on top:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
    geom_point(col=ifelse(x$B, 'blue', ifelse(x$A, 'red', 'black')), size=4) +
    geom_point(col=ifelse(x$A, 'red', ifelse(x$B, 'blue', 'black')))
```

[image]

Or you could experiment with different shape types, or something like that.